# How to output five lists from a loop?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import re
with open("C:\\Corpora\\record-13.txt") as f:
    concepts = f.readlines()
    j = 0
    for line in concepts:
       PATTERN = re.compile(r'''((?:[^ "]|"[^"]*")+)''')
       TokCurrLineCon = PATTERN.split(line)[1::2]
       temp = TokCurrLineCon[1].split(':')
       StartLineNum[j] = temp[0]
       StartOffset[j] = temp[1]
       temp = TokCurrLineCon[2].split('||')
       EndOfCon[j] = temp[0]
       TypeOfCon[j] = temp[1]
       temp = EndOfCon[j].split(':')
       EndLineNum[j] = temp[0]
       EndOffset[j] = temp[1]
       temp = TypeOfCon[j].split('"')
       TypeOfCon[j] = temp[1]
       j +=1
```

I need 5 lists as the end (StartLineNum, StartOffset, EndLineNum, EndOffset, TypeOfCon), but when I run it I face the error `StartLineNum[j] = temp[0]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This is not your code; this doesn't set the initial values for `StartLineNum`, etc., so it just raises a `NameError`. And it seems very likely that the bug is in the part of the code you haven't shown us, which makes it hard to debug.

Comment: You probably meant to initialize `StartLineNum = []` (an empty list), and do `StartLineNum.append(temp[0])` inside the loop.  Etc. ;-)  The error msg clearly says that your `StartLineNum` is actually a string, not a list.

Comment: As a side note, there is no reason to use `readlines()` here. Just do `for line in f:`, and it will have the same effect, except without having to wait to read the entire file into memory and parse it into lines before you even get to the loop. (In fact, [there is _never_ a good reason to use `readlines()`](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html).)

Comment: As another side note, if you want to have a variable like `j` that's always the index in the list you're looping over, just use `for j, line in enumerate(concepts):`. That's simpler and more readable, and it avoids a number of places you could insert stupid bugs. (And if you're like most good programmers, you will insert stupid bugs every chance you give yourself.)

Comment: Also: When you're dealing with Windows pathnames, it's nicer to use raw strings (`r"C:\Corpora\record-13.txt"`), for exactly the same reason you're already using them for your regexp: you don't have to escape the backslashes.

Comment: And finally, the whole point of using `re.compile` and then calling methods on the result is to avoid re-compiling the regexp over and over again. So if you're going to do it, do it _before_ the loop, not each time through the loop. (Or, alternatively, just call `re.split` with your un-compiled pattern.)

Comment: @TimPeters Thank you, but I have 2 lists inside the loop (EndOfCon, TypeOfCon) which I need to split them again. Would that be a problem with `split()`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  How about you take the suggestions @abamert gave you, and post the new code in a new question?:

Comment: @MACEE: You can't `split` a list. If you want to split each of the strings in a list, you need to do that with a loop (whether a `for` statement or a comprehension), or something equivalent like a call to `map`. But it's impossible to give more specific advice without a more specific question, so please do as Tim Peters suggested and post your new question as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `StartLineNum` is a `str`, so `StartLineNum[j] = <anything>` is illegal.

From your description, it sounds like you expected `StartLineNum` to be a `list`. So presumably the problem is that you constructed a string instead of a list somewhere in the code above. Since we can't see that code, we can't fix it, beyond saying that you should create a list if you want a list.

However, I suspect there's another problem in your code. For this to work, `StartLineNum` would have to be not just a list, but a list that's already got as many members as the file has lines. But you can't know how many that is until you've read the whole file in. A better solution would be to use the `append` method on lists. (Then you don't need the `j` variable, either.) For example:

```
StartLineNum = []
for line in concepts:
    # blah blah
    StartLineNum.append(temp[0])
    # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I will try to fix it and if I can't I will ask it as a new question.